# Populate p:dataTable from MySQL using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I want to populate a `<p:dataTable>` but I want to populate it from MySQL database and I want to use Hibernate queries for it. I use JSF.

Here is an image of my work. I want to view all the registered users.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in your managed bean with desired List type-

```
public List<DesiredType> getInfo() {
        return daoObject.getUserInfo();
}
```

Now in your dao implementation-

```
    public List<DesiredType> getUserInfo() {
        String hql = "from EntityName";
        Query q = sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hql);
        List<DesiredType> list = q.list();
        return list;
    }
```

Now call **getInfo()** from xhtml page to populate the data table. Hope this help.